# Firefox page “moves” when hiding/showing divs

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, firefox

I know this question has been asked before, but my case is different and I have not found a solution yet. This is my problem:

I have a checkbox that when you click it, a hidden div becomes visible. However, my page shifts-moves to the left. However, with my case there is no scrollbar that appears.

If I click the checkbox again, the div is hidden and the page shifts to the right again. And this only happens in Firefox (so far). Tried it in Chrome and it didn't happen.

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
   <div class="modelsdiv">
      <form id="models" name="models" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
        <fieldset>

          <label for="type" id="type" class="title">Artist type: <span class="required">*</span>&nbsp;<span class="small">Can be more then 1</span></label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="arttype[]" id="modelbox" class="typebox" value="Model" required=""><span class="box">Model</span><br /> 
<div class="modelinfo">
.....
```

**JS**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#modelbox').click(function(){
        $(".modelinfo").slideToggle('slow');
        $(this).toggleClass('divactive');
    });
```

**CSS**

```
body {
background: #323132;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
.modelsdiv {
display: table;
width: 100%;
}
form {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}
form label {
display: block;
margin-bottom:.2em;
font-family:"Inconsolata", sans-serif;
font-size:15px;
line-height:15px;
color:#BDBDBD;
text-align: left;
font-weight: bold;
}
form label.error {
color:#DF0101;
}
form label.errorg, label.errort {
display: none;
color:#DF0101;
}
form textarea { 
margin-bottom:5px;
font-family:"Inconsolata", sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
font-size:1.4rem;
box-shadow:none;
-moz-box-shadow:none;
-webkit-box-shadow:none;
background:#6E6E6E;
border:1px solid #BDBDBD;
-moz-border-radius:0.2em 0.2em 0.2em 0.2em;
-webkit-border-radius:0.2em 0.2em 0.2em 0.2em;
border-radius:0.2em 0.2em 0.2em 0.2em;
color: #BDBDBD;
width:359px; 
height:192px;
}
form input[type="text"], form input[type="tel"], form input[type="email"], form input[type="url"] {
margin-bottom:5px;
font-family:"Inconsolata", sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
font-size:1.4rem;
box-shadow:none;
-moz-box-shadow:none;
-webkit-box-shadow:none;
background:#6E6E6E;
border:1px solid #BDBDBD;
-moz-border-radius:0.2em 0.2em 0.2em 0.2em;
-webkit-border-radius:0.2em 0.2em 0.2em 0.2em;
border-radius:0.2em 0.2em 0.2em 0.2em;
color: #BDBDBD;
}
fieldset {
border:0px;
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
width: 350px;
}
.required {
color:#c0392b;
}
#success, #error {
display:none;
}
#success span, #error span {
display:block;
position:fixed;
top:40%;
left:36%;
}
#success span p, #error span p {
}
#success span p {
color:#01DF01;
}
#error span p {
color:#DF0101;
}
input[type="submit"] {
border:3px #BDBDBD solid;   
background-color: #1C1C1C;
color: #BDBDBD;
-webkit-border-radius:40px;
-moz-border-radius:40px;
border-radius:40px;
width: 100px;
height: 40px;
}
.box {
color: #BDBDBD;
font-family:"Inconsolata", sans-serif;
}
.small {
font-family:"Inconsolata", sans-serif;
font-size:15px;
line-height:15px;
color:#BDBDBD;
text-align: left;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: normal;
}
.modelinfo {
display: none;
}
.divactive {
display: inline-block;
}
```

I have tried different display types and positions, but it keeps happening.

I hope someone can help!

Comment: Where is `.muainfo` in your HTML markup?

Comment: @zgood: Edited my post. Was a typo. Thanks for showing.

Comment: Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f4pkyfoy/), I see nothing strange in there.

Comment: @skobaljic if you add a longer strings to `<div class="modelinfo">` you'll see the "jump"

Comment: He said, in his case `However, with my case there is no scrollbar that appears`, which means the content length does not matter (which I doubt is true and therefor I created the fiddle).

Comment: @ChrisG thanks for the link, try my edited answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem for this is that firefox has trouble with display: table; for some reason. I had to change the following code:

```
.modelsdiv {
display: table;
width: 100%;
}
```

To:

```
.modelsdiv {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: center;
width: 100%;
}
```

You can also use display: block or whatever, but for me - to keep things centered- this was the way to go.

Thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Playing around with your CSS I noticed that the `display: table ;` is causing the "hiccup"...

```
.modelsdiv {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 15% ;/*select a suitable value :) */
}
```

---

Every browser got its own "css default values" that affect in some cases the aspect of the web they display... I can't be sure it is your case, but you could try resetting some values in the beginning of your css file:

```
/*html, body, div... the tags you want to reset... or '*' for all.*/
html, body{
 margin: 0 ;
 padding: 0 ;
 /*include all attributes you think are suitable...*/
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sadly enough that didn't help. But thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: I just found that out aswell. But using display: block; moves everything to the left. So I added display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: center; and it's centered. With this, no more moving to the left! Stupid that firefox has a problem with this... You can add this to your post and I'll mark it as answered :)

Comment: Yes, every browser implements components in different ways... Thanks, but you find the answer, not me, maybe you should post the answer to it :D I'll vote you hehehe